# How to load an image in R Keras after doing some adjustments to the image using imager

Tags: python, r, image, keras, computer-vision

how can I load an image into Keras with the `image_load` function after I have done some adjustments to the image using the `imager` package in R?

```
library(keras)
library(imager)

img.url <- "https://s3.amazonaws.com/keras.io/img/keras-logo-2018-large-1200.png"
download.file(img.url,'logo.png', mode = 'wb')

img <- load.image("logo.png")

###############################
# Perform some adjustments to the image
###############################

save.image(img, "logo_adj.png")

img_height <- 100
img_width <- 100

img.keras <- keras::image_load(
  'logo_adj.png', 
  target_size = c(img_height, img_width), 
  grayscale = FALSE
)
```

When I use this script, I receive the error message:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ImportError: Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `array_to_img` requires PIL.
```

Does someone know how to solve this?

Comment: Did you check that the Python package Pillow is installed?

Comment: Yes, I have Pillow 5.4.1 installed in my conda environment and I am using that conda environment. When not saving and loading the image using imager, the error does not occur

Comment: Ok, and does calling `reticulate::import("PIL.Image")` work?

Comment: Nope, that does not work and gives the error:  ImportError: DLL load failed